# Theano Tutorial Computing the Jacobian with Scan

Tags: theano, deep-learning, theano.scan

In the Theano Tutorial:

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/gradients.html

or

```
>>> import theano
>>> import theano.tensor as T
>>> x = T.dvector('x')
>>> y = x ** 2
>>> J, updates = theano.scan(lambda i, y,x : T.grad(y[i], x), sequences=T.arange(y.shape[0]), non_sequences=[y,x])
>>> f = theano.function([x], J, updates=updates)
>>> f([4, 4])
array([[ 8.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  8.]])
```

"theano.scan" is used to compute the Jacobian. I understand how to compute the Jacobian by hand but I do not quite understand how the function scan is calculating it iteratively; specifically, I don't understand how the "zeroes" are obtained in the Jacobian.

Can someone show me, for each iteration, how this is calculated? Thanks!